# How to identify a finalized query?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I perform a query (which is asynchronous) in firebase reference. I need to know when this consultation ends to make a decision after the data is loaded. Already researched and thought a lot and I can not think of a solution.

```
Firebase refEventTypeFirebase = refUserPrivate.child(EventType.EventTypeEnum.NODE_NAME.text);
Query queryEventType = refEventTypeFirebase .orderByKey();
queryEventType.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
@Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        // If I have several children in the query, 
        // this method will be called several times until the last "dataSnapshot".
        //How to identify the last time he runs into a given query?
    }
    ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Firebase a query is never finished. Instead it synchronizes data, both data that existed before you attached the listener *and* any new data that comes in after you attach the listener. So instead of waiting for a query result, you listen to all data (existing and new) and stop listening when you no longer care about the data.

If you only care about the current data, you can attach a single-value event listener:

```
queryEventType.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChanged(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot child: snapshot.getChildren()) {
            // do the thing that you were going to do in onChildAdded
        }
    }
    ...
```

But by taking this approach, you'll be giving up one of the biggest benefits of Firebase. It's often better to build your application logic around the fact that the data changes and that you'll be receiving those changes in real-time.

Comment: Man, thank you, it was just that I wanted, not exactly, but serves my purpose. Actually I had already tried this alternative, but when I tried could not convert the objects directly because it was like this: `PojoObject pojo = snapshot.getValue(PojoObject .class);`. When in fact I had to make a covering for all the children. `for (DataSnapshot child: snapshot.getChildren()) {
            // do the thing that you were going to do in onChildAdded
        }`. Thank you again.

Comment: And it helped me understand even better than the other listener never ends, for he is always listening for change. Silly thing but had not repaired.